# Magnifier icon shows up when I zoom in/out with a pinch on the touchpad

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, touchpad, zoom

I'm having a problem with my touchpad. It now shows a magnifier icon, instead of the mouse's arrow pointer, at the screen when I pinch the touchpad with two fingers for doing the zoom in/out movement; and the image zoom is now very slow and difficult to do. It wasn't this way before. Maybe it's some misconfiguration at someplace. I've tried mouse configs, Elan Smart-Pad configs, and many other places, but no luck. I just want to remove the pointer magnifier icon and have back the standard pinch with the standard mouse's arrow pointer and smooth image zoom in/out. Below are some pics showing the magnifier pointer icon.

My setup is: 
Laptop Acer Aspire M5-481PT 
Windows 10 21H1

It used to have as programs for touchpad:

Elan Smart-Pad (Driver: ETDWare PS/2-X64 11.6.27.201_WHQL) 
TouchPad Synaptics 17.0.6.13_W81x64_A

The Elan Smart-Pad program/driver makes my touchpad more versatile and works better for me.

[image]

Comment: Is *Magnifier* turned on in the  *Ease of Access* control panel?

Comment: Hi, DrMoishe. Thanks for the try. It's not the Accessibility Magnifier. It's just the mouse's arrow pointer that turns into a magnifier pointer when I make the pinch movement on the touchpad for zooming in/out. I don't know where it comes from, if it's from Windows, Synaptics, Elantech or somewhere else.